# JavaFX: CSS isn't picked up during offscreen rendering of Text

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8, rendering, off-screen

I'm trying to pre-render some `Text` elements offscreen to retrieve their widths before rendering them later on-screen:

```
Group offScreenRoot = new Group();
Scene offScreen = new Scene(offScreenRoot, 1024, 768);
Set<Text> textSet = new HashSet<>();

Text textText = new Text(getText());
textSet.add(textText);

Text idText = new Text(getId());

textSet.add(idText);

for (String s : getStrings()) {
    textSet.add(new Text(s));
}
for (Text text : textSet) {
    text.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 48;"); // <- HERE!
    text.applyCss();
    offScreenRoot.getChildren().add(text);
}
for (Text text : textSet) {
    System.out.println(text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
}
```

I'm applying a large font size via CSS, but this doesn't get picked up. Instead, the `Text` is as wide as it would be, rendered in the default font size (I guess).

Is there a way to render a `Text` off-screen and get the actual width value as per CSS font size?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand the purpose of your code. It would have been easier with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please keep it mind for the next time.

I think you made some simple mistakes. Looking at the [applyCss definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) You should apply the applyCss on the parent's node, not on the node. 
Another thing important in the doc is :

> Provided that the Node's Scene is not null

And unfortunately when you apply your CSS, the text's scene is null as it not yet added to his parent.

```
text.applyCss();
offScreenRoot.getChildren().add(text);
```

So there is two solutions, as described in the code below in comment (and especially in the for loop where you add Texts to the parent) :

```
public class MainOffscreen extends Application {

   private List<String> stringsList = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      // Populates stringsList
      stringsList.add("String1");
      stringsList.add("String2");
      stringsList.add("String3");
      stringsList.add("String4");

      VBox offscreenRootVbox = new VBox(10.0);
      Scene offScreen = new Scene(offscreenRootVbox, 900, 700);

      // Replace the Hashset by list in order to keep order, more interesting for testing.
      List<Text> textSet = new ArrayList();

      // Text text.
      Text textText = new Text("Text");
      textSet.add(textText);

      // Text id.
      Text idText = new Text("Id");
      textSet.add(idText);

      // Populate String list.
      for(String s: stringsList) {
         textSet.add(new Text(s));
      }

      // Print the width of Texts before applying Css.
      for(Text text: textSet) {
         System.out.println("BEFORE Width of " + text.getText() + " : " + text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
      }
      System.out.println("\n----------\n");

      for(Text text: textSet) {
         text.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 48;"); // <- HERE!
         // First add it to the parent.
         offscreenRootVbox.getChildren().add(text);

         // Either apply the CSS on the each Text, or Apply it on the parent's Text, I choose the
         // second solution.
         // text.applyCss();
      }
      // Apply the css on the parent's node
      offscreenRootVbox.applyCss();

      for(Text text: textSet) {
         System.out.println("AFTER Width of " + text.getText() + " : " + text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
      }

      // primaryStage.setScene(offScreen);
      // primaryStage.show();
   }
}
```

And it gives this output :

```
BEFORE Width of Text : 22.13671875
BEFORE Width of Id : 10.259765625
BEFORE Width of String1 : 37.845703125
BEFORE Width of String2 : 37.845703125
BEFORE Width of String3 : 37.845703125
BEFORE Width of String4 : 37.845703125

----------

AFTER Width of Text : 88.546875
AFTER Width of Id : 41.0390625
AFTER Width of String1 : 151.3828125
AFTER Width of String2 : 151.3828125
AFTER Width of String3 : 151.3828125
AFTER Width of String4 : 151.3828125
```

Hope this helps you.